# Using Storyboard how to interact with viewcontroller objects

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard

I've reviewed many websites and youtube videos that have IOS 5 storyboarding information.  Most of them are pretty basic and only describe how to get started with storyboarding and how to segue into other views.  I'm interested in taking it a step further and actually adding custom code to the views contained within the storyboard.

Is the "normal" workflow when creating an IOS app using storyboard?

1. Create the layout of an app using storyboard (adding views and objects to those views).
2. Create viewcontroller files (.h and .m), one for each view contained within the storyboard.
3. Hook up the scenes from the storyboard with your own view controller subclasses by editing the "class" values in Identity Inspector.

I believe I followed those steps, but when I implemented step #3 above and ran my application, I was only able to see a black screen.  The view I had created in storyboard wouldn't display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right steps. Make sure you create your .m and .h without a xib. Post your code for the view controller for your first view to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is the normal workflow. have you set the "initial viewcontroller?  ?
see this image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31437518/Screen%20Shot%202012-01-24%20at%2012.29.34%20AM.png

Comment: Yes, I have set the initial viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you made a storyboard file but it isn't being loaded.

Do you have the main storyboard setting in the target summary screen filled in?